Segment compilation is happening for most of our REDSHIFT queries which is adding to our query performance
We  are running  range restricted query in our redshift where only the  employee_id and  business_date keep changing .But we keep seeing in SVL_COMPILE our hourly segment compilation is very high .Most of the queries are getting compiled which is adding additional time to the query.
This query keep getting executed with different employee_id and business_date range by our product team .

Hourly hit : 1500 queries per hour.

Date Format for business_date field: : yyyy-MM-dd

tillTime is a timestamp field with constant value as 9999-01-01 01:00:00 . We had keep tillTime in query as we  set tillTime to current date while milestoning the entry.Only active records will have the value as 9999-01-01 01:00:00.

Queries are getting executing from an spring boot app Deployed in
EC2 having instance count as 10.

employee_id  : Can go from 1 to 5 employee_id  max.

business_date range from 1 day to 30 days

columns: We have 216 columns in table. So the db column in select queries are dynamic based on user selection.We only fetch those columns that user has requested.


Query:
Select coulmns from acconts table where   business_date between (?) and (?) and employee_id in (?) and  sysdate >tillTime.

Our table configuration is:
Sortkey: (SORTKEY(business_date,employee_id ,snap_type,tillTime))
Diststyle: AUTO(EVEN)

Our cluster configuration is:
Node type: ra3.xlplue
Number of nodes: 10

We tried below:
Query:
Select coulmns  from acconts table where business_date between (?) and (?) and  emmployee_id in (?) and 
tillTime='9999-01-01 01:00:00'

Still not much improvement observed .
Any body can guide here on why segment compiled when sysdate >tillTime or when tillTime='9999-01-01 01:00:00'

Lots of possibilities here so going to throw out some ideas to explore.  More info needed to narrow down what to focus on.
My first guess is that the compiler algorithm is changing between runs due to options being sent to Redshift.  The IN clause can be compiled differently depending on how many values are in the IN clause.  A few values and this will compile as a list of OR conditions.  Many values and the compiler will use a pseudo-join structure.  The plans are different and deciding to change would cause a recompile.
This type of significant change in is what you are likely looking for. My guess is just that a guess.  Take a look at the explain plans before and after a recompile and see what changes between them.  Clues are likely needed.
Your table definition and state of metadata validity are also important.  This info is used to decide which compiler algorithm to use so if it gets meaningfully out of date decisions can change.  Is your table changing every hour?  How often are you updating and analyzing?

hello @bill  ,yes we have  data load going on through out the day..as we are event based system..we keep getting data through out the day .Yes i have seen every time query plan is with OR condition only it creates ..our max employee_id is 5   as part of in clause. Just out of curiosity  sysdate >tillTime. ,is this Sysdate can be a cause?We run analyze weekly once.Our stats_off will be around 1% max weekly before we run analyze.

Hello @Bill Weiner, if there  is  sysdate in my select query eg:   sysdate >tillTime, will it make my query  segment to compile more number of times than expected.

Sysdate shouldn't be a cause of recompile but I have no insight to prove this.  It is just the transaction start time which should just be another replaceable value in the query plan - just like between values you compare to business_date.  Do you see any changes in the query plans comparing before and after recompiles?

As to metadata changes causing recompile - You may only have 1% stats off but this is for the entire table.  Depending on your sort keys and WHERE conditions of the query Redshift could determine that a high percentage of the needed blocks are stats off.  For example if business_date is the sort key and the query is looking at dates within the past week these blocks can have no valid zone maps.  This could cause a recompile if an earlier run had very high use of metadata.

Hello @bill Weiner, since our system is event based system  and we batch the data and load.So, should we run analyze on every copy command

On a busy system with many updates coming in, once per week analyze may be too infrequent.  With every COPY may be too frequent and impact overall cluster performance.  Data is needed more than opinion.  If an experiment is what is needed I'd try moving to daily analyze (and possibly vacuum) and see if this improves the compile situation.  I'm not convinced that out of date stats are the cause of your issue.  Diagnostic information is what I'd be looking for.
